# phonegap upload issue after build

Tags: cordova

```
    function getImage() {
        Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
        alert('File Not Selected');
    },{
        quality: 50, 
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
    }
        );

    }

    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="uploaded";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "abc.php", win, fail, options);
    }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        alert(r.response);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " +error.code);
    }
```

This works fine on an android emulator through eclipse. When the upload button is pressed and it asks for a file to upload; it fails when apk file is created by phonegap run on device no upload button work. I have to remove phonegap.js also.

Answer (score 0):

Is the camera plugin added to config.xml?

```
<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you have to remove phonegap.js ?

If you do that you can not access any device APIs as they are dependent on the device specific phonegap.js being in the app. This will be injected at build time on PhoneGap Build.